# How to build docker image for multiple platforms with cross-compile?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, docker-registry, multiplatform

I'm trying to build a multi platform (linux/amd64,linux/arm64) node image. As far as I understood I can try the corss-compile approach. Building with docker buildx and pushing to the docker registry did not throw any errors. Running the image on the build machine also works fine, but on my raspberry-pi4 (running ubuntu 64bit) following occurs after pulling the image

> exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM node:18-alpine as node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN echo "console.log('hello world!');" > main.js
EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "node", "main.js" ]
```

I builded and pushed my image the following way:

`docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t buntel/node-multi-arch --push .`

I ran my container the following way (no problem on my laptop, but fails on my raspberry-pi):

`docker run --rm -it buntel/node-multi-arch`

In the docker registry I also see tags for both platforms
https://hub.docker.com/r/buntel/node-multi-arch/tags.
What's going wrong here?

Additional info:

`docker buildx ls`:

> NAME/NODE       DRIVER/ENDPOINT             STATUS  BUILDKIT PLATFORMS
> loving_tesla *  docker-container
> loving_tesla0 unix:///var/run/docker.sock running v0.10.4
> linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386 default
> docker                                          default       default
> running 20.10.18 linux/amd64, linux/386

`docker buildx inspect`:

> Name:   loving_tesla Driver: docker-container
>
> Nodes: Name:      loving_tesla0 Endpoint:  unix:///var/run/docker.sock
> Status:    running Buildkit:  v0.10.4 Platforms: linux/amd64,
> linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386

laptop: `docker version`

> Client:  Version:           20.10.18  API version:       1.41  Go
> version:        go1.19.1  Git commit:        b40c2f6b5d  Built:
> Sat Sep 10 11:31:10 2022  OS/Arch:           linux/amd64  Context:
> default  Experimental:      true
>
> Server:  Engine:   Version:          20.10.18   API version:      1.41
> (minimum version 1.12)   Go version:       go1.19.1   Git commit:
> e42327a6d3   Built:            Sat Sep 10 11:30:17 2022   OS/Arch:
> linux/amd64   Experimental:     false  containerd:   Version:
> v1.6.8   GitCommit:        9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6.m
> runc:   Version:          1.1.4   GitCommit:          docker-init:
> Version:          0.19.0   GitCommit:        de40ad0

raspberry-pi `docker version`:

> Client: Docker Engine - Community  Version:           20.10.18  API
> version:       1.41  Go version:        go1.18.6  Git commit:
> b40c2f6  Built:             Thu Sep  8 23:10:58 2022  OS/Arch:
> linux/arm64  Context:           default  Experimental:      true
>
> Server: Docker Engine - Community  Engine:   Version:
> 20.10.18   API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)   Go version:       go1.18.6   Git commit:       e42327a   Built:           Thu Sep  8
> 23:09:16 2022   OS/Arch:          linux/arm64   Experimental:
> false  containerd:   Version:          1.6.8   GitCommit:
> 9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6  runc:   Version:
> 1.1.4   GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d  docker-init:   Version:          0.19.0   GitCommit:        de40ad0

UPDATE:

In my case, I didn't need to emulate anything, because I didn't handle binary builds. So for me, the key was to use `--platform=$BUILDPLATFORM` on my build stage and `--platform=$TARGETPLATFORM` on the final stage. This will use the architecture of the machine building the docker image to build my JavaScript/Typescript. And then switch to the target architecture when collecting the build artifacts, which can then be run by those machines.

Example:

```
FROM node:18-alpine as node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN echo "console.log('hello world!');" > main.js


FROM --platform=$TARGETPLATFORM node:18-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=node /usr/src/app/main.js .

CMD [ "node", "main.js" ]

EXPOSE 4000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you're using `BUILDPLATFORM`, which will always be the same architecture as the host machine. In this case, it will always be x86_64. What you want is the `TARGETPLATFORM`, which will be implicit anyway. You can see this in an explanation of multi-platform Docker [builds](https://github.com/BretFisher/multi-platform-docker-build#recommended-approach-for-curl-and-wget-commands-in-multi-platform-dockerfiles).

You can get the Docker info using `docker version | grep 'OS/Arch'` (this will give the client first, then the server).

What you actually want is to use the `node:18-alpine` image for the `linux/arm64` when building for that platform. Changing it to the following will work:

```
FROM node:18-alpine as node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN echo "console.log('hello world!');" > main.js
EXPOSE 4000

CMD [ "node", "main.js" ]
```

If you still want to build for `linux/amd64` and run it on your ARMv8 machine, you would have to install [binfmt](https://github.com/tonistiigi/binfmt) to register these x86_64 binaries with the correct Qemu emulator. This would be then emulating x86_64 on your ARM machine, which you almost certainly do not want to do.

Answer (score 5):

Both of your images were built for your build platform rather than the target platform with this line:

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM ...
```

You don't want `--platform=$BUILDPLATFORM` on the target stage. This is used on the intermediate stages that either cross compile or output non-platform specific results that you can copy into the target stage.

More details on these variables defined by buildkit is available at: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#automatic-platform-args-in-the-global-scope

I'd also change your RUN step to a COPY step, which eliminates the need for any emulation on the build server. This means running:

```
echo "console.log('hello world!');" > main.js
```

in the same directory with your Dockerfile, to create the `main.js` file in your build context. Then change the Dockerfile to have:

```
FROM node:18-alpine as node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY main.js .
EXPOSE 4000
CMD [ "node", "main.js" ]
```

With that you can build multi-platform images using your original `docker buildx build` command.

Comment: What do I have to do to build for both platforms? Can I put the run command into another build step and. Copy the results from there to the final stage, to circumvent emulation? I don't build any binary files, just compiling some JavaScript and typescript.

Comment: What I was trying to do is: Build my JavaScript (In this case just create a single file) and then tell docker for arm64 platform you need to pull the arm64 node image and then add my JavaScript files from previous build steps.

Comment: @Buntel I've updated to clarify. Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `BUILDPLATFORM` is always going to be `linux/amd64`, when you probably want `linux/arm64` which is implicit (or can use `TARGETPLATFORM`. In order to get this to run, you'd have to install binfmt, but this would the emulate amd64 on the arm64 host. That's the more clear answer.

Comment: In my case I don't need to emulate. But this was my mistake. If you post this as an answer I would mark it as the solution. Big thanks @AlexHuszagh!

Comment: `BUILDPLATFORM` won't always be `linux/amd64`, it will always be the architecture of the node you are building on. If the image was built on an arm64 host, it's would be `linux/arm64`. It's also not needed to specify `TARGETPLATFORM` since it's the default platform. Qemu's binfmt_misc is only needed if you have `RUN` steps, and it's configured by default on Docker Desktop. You can also use binfmt_misc to run images built for other platforms, but that's a different question than what's asked here.